# How to use inticap and leave last part in capital letter in postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a table with address all in capital but I am trying to format it like this:

145 WELLBEING STREET, PARADE, LONDON, PP1 5PP

145 Wellbeing Street, Parade, London, PP1 5PP

How can i work with that? I have tried, converting all with initcap:

```
UPDATE address_table
SET field_address = initcap(field_address)
```

And then it pick the last piece and convert it in Uppercase:

```
UPDATE address_table
SET field_address = upper(regexp_replace(field_address , '^.*,', ''))
```

So i thought in concatenate but still i have the last piece in initcap...

I have also tried with :

```
SELECT field_address || upper(trim(reverse(split_part(reverse(field_address ), ',', 1)))) FROM address_table
```

but the results i got are like i.e.

Southridge,  Newbury Hill, Hampstead Norreys, Thatcham, Rg18 0trRG18 0TR

How can i delete the last part after the last comma to convert it in capital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Postgres 14 :**

```
UPDATE address_table
   SET field_address = initcap(replace(field_address, split_part(field_address, ',', -1), '')) || split_part(field_address, ',', -1)
```

**From Postgres 10 :**

```
UPDATE address_table
   SET field_address = initcap(regexp_replace(field_address, '[^,]+$', '')) || (regexp_match(field_address, '[^,]+$'))[1]
```

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=769d4f971943e4bbec6ed087952cc87a).

Comment: I have tried similar and i got that field position must be greater than zero, i tried and get the same for your solution.

Comment: look at the result in [dbffidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1fc9c163a109688b9f5ac401856cbcc8) which works well. What is your postgres version ?

Comment: it seems that for version earliest than 14 doesn't work.

Comment: You are right : the split_part function accepts negative positions only from pg version 14. Answer is updated with an alternative solution from pg version 10.

Comment: thanks! yes that seems to do the magic...